# eqref from another documents perspective

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing, input

In the following code, I have two documents sharing the same input file (myeq.tex), which has a labeled equation. In Document 1, the equation would be referred to as equation 1 since it is the first occurrence of that equation in Document 1. In Document 2, however, it will be equation (2).
How can I force Document 2 to see it from Document 1s perspective (i.e. equation 1 instead of 2)?

myeq.tex:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
x + y = z
\end{equation}
```

Document 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\input{myeq.tex}

This equation \eqref{eq1}.

\end{document}
```

Document 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,latexsym,amssymb,exscale,relsize,caption,subfig,textcomp,tikz,stackrel,setspace,float}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[]{document1.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x + y = z
\end{equation}

\input{myeq.tex}

This equation \eqref{eq1}.

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1. Your code cannot work, because you cannot use `\input` to read a file with `\begin{document}` inside the document body of `Document1` or `Document2`. 2. You could use package `xr` to cross reference the equation number of the first document. But this would only change the number of the reference. If you also want to change the number of the equation, you would have to use manual tags (e.g., using package `amsmath`) also using the cross reference. To give a real answer instead of a comment, I would need more details and a minimal working example instead of not working code snippets.

Comment: I am using the xr package, xr-hyper and my editor allows "External typesetter" (I'm using Texifier). I've updated the packages, please double check. Thanks a lot for your help @cabohah.

Comment: the posted code will give errors as you can not use `\input` on the file shown.  If you just want to refererence the equation you could make two documents and use `xr`  bur if you want to typeset the equation in both documents with the same number, it's a bit harder and we need more information about the requirements

Comment: do you want document 2 to have two equations both labelled (1) ?? if not how do you want the input equation to be (1) ?

Comment: as posted there is no `\documentclass` so none of the three files will make any output

Comment: I have edited thanks to your comments, then tested locally and now it works @DavidCarlisle

Comment: you fixed the errors but it is still not clear what output you want. document 2 has two equations, with a reference to the second one, you say you want the reference to print as (1)  do you want both equations to print as (1) or do you want the second equation to be printed as (2) but the reference to it say (1) ????

Comment: The most important thing is that the reference in Document 2 should be equation (1), because i want it to reference the equation in Document 1. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

some comments added inline:

---

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}% bad style to use numbers in labels
x + y = z
\end{equation}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\input{myeq.tex}

This equation \eqref{eq1}.

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,latexsym,amssymb,exscale,relsize,caption,subfig,textcomp,tikz,stackrel,setspace,float}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[d1:]{document1}% no .tex extension

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x + y = z
\end{equation}

\input{myeq.tex}

This equation \eqref{eq1} which is a copy of \eqref{d1:eq1} from document1.

\end{document}
```

---

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you !